# PHP Can't redeclare object in function when called twice

Tags: php, rest, authentication

I'm making a PHP API, and am calling a function to pull a request from our DBHandler. When i get the '/attendees' function, i pull the data correctly. But i want to add authentication into each call to the api. We pass through a param into the DBHandler to to specify which connection string to use (as we have multiple). If the string is defined a null, it will use a standard connection string.

The 'authentication' function needs to user the standard connection string, whilst the '/attendees' get requires a different connection string. As mentioned '/attendees' works fine by itself, but when i add auth it errors out when trying to execute the sql. I know it's because the authenticate is using a different connection string, and is somehow overwriting the connection.

```
require_once '../include/DbHandler.php';
require_once '../include/PassHash.php';
require '.././libs/Slim/Slim.php';
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
\Slim\Slim::registerAutoloader();

$app = new \Slim\Slim();
$user_id = NULL;

 function authenticate(\Slim\Route $route) {
     $headers = apache_request_headers();
     $response = array();
     $app = \Slim\Slim::getInstance();
     $dm_config = null;
     if (isset($headers['Auth'])) {
         $db = new DbHandler($dm_config);
         $api_key = $headers['Auth'];
         if (!$db->isValidApiKey($api_key)) {
             $response["error"] = true;
             $response["message"] = "Access Denied. Invalid Api key";
             echoRespnse(401, $response);
             $app->stop();
         } else {
           $response["error"] = false;
           $response["message"] = "Auth Accepted";
         }
     } else {
         $response["error"] = true;
         $response["message"] = "Api key is misssing";
         echoRespnse(400, $response);
         $app->stop();
     }
 }

$app->get('/attendees','authenticate', function() {
            global $event_id;
            $headers = apache_request_headers();
            $event_id = $headers['Eventid'];
            $dm_config = $headers['Dm'];
            $user_id = null;
            $response = array();
            $db = new DbHandler($dm_config);
            $result = $db->getAttendees($user_id, $event_id);
            $response["error"] = false;
            $response["nav"] = array();
            while ($task = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                $tmp = array();
                $tmp["ea.id"] = $task["ea.id"];
                array_push($response["nav"], $tmp);
            }
            echoRespnse(200, $response);
        });
```

How do i get the function to call the same object but use separately?

Answer (score 1):

You are passing the same connection string `$dm_config` in both functions.

You should have a different variable for each connection.

Comment: A rookie mistake, but unfortunately doesn't make any difference

Comment: In `authenticate()` variable  `$dm_config` is passed as null to the constructor. Is this intentional?

Comment: Yes, the constructor knows if it's supplied null to use a specific connenction string

Answer (score 1):

you can do by declaring `static $db` variable initialized by null and use before connect db check it empty or not by empty() function.

```
function authenticate(\Slim\Route $route) {
     static $db=null;
     $headers = apache_request_headers();
     $response = array();
     $app = \Slim\Slim::getInstance();
     $dm_config = null;
     if (isset($headers['Auth'])) {
         if(empty($db))
         {
             $db = new DbHandler($dm_config);
         }
         $api_key = $headers['Auth'];
         if (!$db->isValidApiKey($api_key)) {
             $response["error"] = true;
             $response["message"] = "Access Denied. Invalid Api key";
             echoRespnse(401, $response);
             $app->stop();
         } else {
           $response["error"] = false;
           $response["message"] = "Auth Accepted";
         }
     } else {
         $response["error"] = true;
         $response["message"] = "Api key is misssing";
         echoRespnse(400, $response);
         $app->stop();
     }
 }
```

OR you can make global variable $db and access it by global keyword in both function as mentioned  below

```
require_once '../include/DbHandler.php';
require_once '../include/PassHash.php';
require '.././libs/Slim/Slim.php';
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
\Slim\Slim::registerAutoloader();

$app = new \Slim\Slim();
$user_id = NULL;

$db=null; //global bariable

 function authenticate(\Slim\Route $route) {
     global $db; // access global variable
     $headers = apache_request_headers();
     $response = array();
     $app = \Slim\Slim::getInstance();
     $dm_config = null;
     if (isset($headers['Auth'])) {
         if(!empty($db)) {$db = new DbHandler($dm_config)};
         $api_key = $headers['Auth'];
         if (!$db->isValidApiKey($api_key)) {
             $response["error"] = true;
             $response["message"] = "Access Denied. Invalid Api key";
             echoRespnse(401, $response);
             $app->stop();
         } else {
           $response["error"] = false;
           $response["message"] = "Auth Accepted";
         }
     } else {
         $response["error"] = true;
         $response["message"] = "Api key is misssing";
         echoRespnse(400, $response);
         $app->stop();
     }
 }

$app->get('/attendees','authenticate', function() {
            global $db; // access global variable
            global $event_id;
            $headers = apache_request_headers();
            $event_id = $headers['Eventid'];
            $dm_config = $headers['Dm'];
            $user_id = null;
            $response = array();
            if(!empty($db)) {$db = new DbHandler($dm_config)};
            $result = $db->getAttendees($user_id, $event_id);
            $response["error"] = false;
            $response["nav"] = array();
            while ($task = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
                $tmp = array();
                $tmp["ea.id"] = $task["ea.id"];
                array_push($response["nav"], $tmp);
            }
            echoRespnse(200, $response);
        });
```

Comment: Thanks, it's working slightly better - if i supply the wrong code, i get the correct auth error, however if it's right, the '/attendees' get still errors out. It's like it's not being passed the correct DB. Just to note, i'm factoring the above answer and renaming the variable in authenticate

Comment: Is there any way i can check the result of the authenticate and wrap this around my attendees get so they're not called at the same time?

Comment: you have problem with check authenticate in both method right?.. you can use global variable as i have edited my answer

Comment: Doesn't work unfortunately, in your db is being declared as null, and wrapped around the empty if, so it errors out when db is called in the line below. So i wrapped all the code that calls the db in the empty if, and unsurprisingly, nothing is returned because DB is null